# Copy value form sheet, use as worksheet names (in a loop) - VBA Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am attempting to Copy values in a Row, one by one from each cell, then use those values as worksheet names, one by one.  One of the issues I had was skipping the first batch of sheets, so I attempted to hide the ones I don't want renamed.  All other sheets should be renamed (34 of them).

I can get it all the way "ws.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues" using F8 before I get an error message that says "Run-time error '1004'L Method 'PasteSpecial' of object'_Worksheet' failed.

I have also tried using "Activesheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues" but it gave the same error.

Any suggestions at all are very much appreciated, this is driving me nuts. :)  My back up plan is simply using the macro record and doing every rename manually, but it's not a very elegant or simple code that way, so I'd prefer not to do that.

Here is the Code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim TitleID As String
Dim TID As String


Sheets("SheetName1").Activate
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = ws.Range("C5", "AJ5")

For Each cell In rng
    cell.Copy
    Sheets("SheetName1").Visible = False
    ws.Next.Select
    ws.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next cell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, properly, the below code should work.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("SheetName1")

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = ws.Range("C5","AJ5") 

Dim i as Integer 
i = 5 'this is an arbitrary number, change to whatever number of worksheets 
      'you wish to exclude that are at the beginning (left most side) of your workbook
      'also assumes "SheetName1" is before this number.

For Each cell In rng
    Sheets(i).Name = cell.Value
    i = i + 1
Next cell
```

Comment: Yes!  It works perfectly.  Thank you so much, I am very new to Excel macros/VBA, so every step is a struggle/learning opportunity.  :)

Comment: If you call `Range` with two arguments, it uses them as the top-left and bottom-right corner so `Range("C5","AJ5")` is the same as  `Range("C5:AJ5")`. `Range("C5,AJ5")` would be just the two cells.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct - thanks for that. I knew I felt like I was deceiving myself with that comment. I'll edit that out.